# как получить value всех выбранных checkbox javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как получить значение всех выбранных checkbox через JavaScript?

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" />
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Всё просто, с помощью `JavaScript` к примеру, берем все чекбоксы по классу [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) и смотрим в цикле, кто выбран

```js
function getCheckedCheckBoxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  var checkboxesChecked = []; // можно в массиве их хранить, если нужно использовать 
  for (var index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
     if (checkboxes[index].checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[index].value); // положим в массив выбранный
        alert(checkboxes[index].value); // делайте что нужно - это для наглядности
     }
  }
  return checkboxesChecked; // для использования в нужном месте
}
```

```html
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" />
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" />

<button onclick="getCheckedCheckBoxes()"> Кто выбран? </button>
```

Помимо [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) можно использовать [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) или [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName). В общем, реализаций можно написать много.

Comment: как реализовать без нажатия на button

Comment: вообще суть такая что мне нужно все эти значения потом передать через AJAX

Comment: Смотрите правку. Добавил `return`, то есть перед формированием `AJAX` вызываете метод - получаете массив значений выбранных чек-боксов и все.

Answer (score 2):

Для получения всех отмеченных чекбоксов можно воспользоваться функцией [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) с селектором [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

```js
function getCheckedCheckBoxes() {
  var selectedCheckBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.checkbox:checked');

  var checkedValues = Array.from(selectedCheckBoxes).map(cb => cb.value);

  console.log(checkedValues);

  return checkedValues; // для использования в нужном месте
}
```

```html
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" />
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" />

<button onclick="getCheckedCheckBoxes()"> Кто выбран? </button>
```

Comment: Для es5 отличие будет только в строке, где обьявляется переменная `checkedValues ` -> `var checkedValues = Array.prototype.map.call(selectedCheckBoxes,function(cb){
  return cb.value
})`'

Comment: нужно реализовать без нажатия на button, а по нажатию на checkbox

Comment: @harbor, замени button на checkbox

Comment: хорошо, а можно перечислять значения чекбоксов не через запятую?

Comment: @harbor, функция возвращает _массив_ значений. Можешь его как угодно к строке приводить, если нужно. Либо как массив значений и использовать