# Выбрать какие чекбоксы неактивны

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать проверку. Если у меня выбраны один или несколько чекбоксов filter=one, а все остальные, ни один из них,  не выбраны, то показать сообщение.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
 if ( $('input[filter=one]:checked') && $('input:not([filter=one]):not(:checked)')) {
 alert(1);
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input filter="one" type="checkbox" checked>
<input filter="one" type="checkbox" checked>
<input filter="one" type="checkbox" checked>
<input filter="one" type="checkbox" checked>

<br/>

<input filter="two" type="checkbox">
<input filter="two" type="checkbox" checked>
<input filter="two" type="checkbox">
<input filter="two" type="checkbox">

<br/>

<input filter="three" type="checkbox">
<input filter="three" type="checkbox">
<input filter="three" type="checkbox">
<input filter="three" type="checkbox">

<button>Проверить</button>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить значения всех выбранных checkbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868022/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-checkbox)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649737/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-value-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-checkbox-javascript

Comment: @EzioMercer Не совсем дубликат, логика с группами

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Если честно не очень понимаю сложность посмотреть на выбранные и невыбранные и смотреть куда они относятся, имея в руках алгоритм просмотра выбранных чекбоксов)) Но возможно вам виднее, как лучше ответить)

Comment: @EzioMercer "посмотреть на выбранные и невыбранные" - в этом и проблема у автора вопроса. Нужно посмотреть на **выбранные и выбранные.**

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Я просто подумал, если дам алгоритм нахожденися отмеченных, ровно обратное найти будт не так сложно)

Comment: @EzioMercer Я понял. Просто по коду в вопросе ясно, что автор понимает как получить отмеченные или неотмеченные чекбоксы. Тут вопрос как правильно построить логическое выражение.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Не буду спорить)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Истина должна быть в том случае, если есть хотя бы один выбранный чекбокс в первой группе И ноль выбранных в остальных группах.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let check1 = $('input[filter=one]:checked');
  let check2 = $('input:not([filter=one]):checked');

  if (check1.length > 0 && check2.length == 0) alert(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input filter="one" type="checkbox" checked>
<input filter="one" type="checkbox" checked>
<input filter="one" type="checkbox" checked>
<input filter="one" type="checkbox" checked>

<br/>

<input filter="two" type="checkbox">
<input filter="two" type="checkbox" checked>
<input filter="two" type="checkbox">
<input filter="two" type="checkbox">

<br/>

<input filter="three" type="checkbox">
<input filter="three" type="checkbox">
<input filter="three" type="checkbox">
<input filter="three" type="checkbox">

<button>Проверить</button>
```